# Radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}3^{-|n|}z^{2n}, z \in \mathcal{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to find out the radius of the following power series of a complex variable:

$\displaystyle \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} 3^{-|n|} z^{2n}, z \in \mathbb{C}$

The ration test $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{a_m}{a_{m+1}}\right|$ gives me the radius of convergence as 3 . But I am not really sure how to handle the negative power terms. Should I group same co-efficient terms, and complete the square? But then, I don't get a polynomial in a single variable.

Also, how do I evaluate the sum?

Comment: As far as I know, the radius of convergence is only defined for series with positive indices, not series with negative exponents. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your series is
$$
1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac{z^2}3\bigg)^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\frac1{3z^2}\bigg)^n,
$$
which converges when both $|z^2/3|$ and $|1/3z^2|$ are less than $1$, that is, when $1/\sqrt3<|z|<\sqrt3$.

This is typical of [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series), which are convergent on annuli and thus have both inner and outer "radii of convergence".

Comment: One might not want to encourage the OP to use the term "radius of convergence" to an object to which it does not apply.

Comment: Woudn't this be just a necessary condition for convergence? How can I prove that it actually converges, for e.g. by finding the sum?

Comment: @Did I don't find it damaging to say that a Laurent series, convergent on an annulus, has an inner and outer radius of convergence. At most it's just a matter of terminology.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac Both sums are geometric series, and we know everything there is to know about when geometric series converge. Indeed, you can find the sum exactly in this case; but that's not necessary in general for knowing that a series converges.